# i have 6 columns value1, value2, value3 ,value4 ,value5 ,value6, in a dataframe(csv file)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

## sample data

```
Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5        paring(single column) 
    3     2         4      2       2         [3,2][2,4][4,2][2,2]
    6     7         7      6       6         [6,7][7,7][7,6][6,6]


df = pd.DataFrame(content)

def get_pairs(x):
    arr = x.split(' ')
    return list(map(list, zip(arr, arr[1:])))

df['pairs'] = df.applymap(get_pairs)
```

name content each one have numeric values and what i want to do is to make the pair of it like

eg; 123456 is the values in each column then pairing should be made in separate column name Pairs [1,2],[2,3],[3,4]

Comment: done please can you check

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `apply` with `axis=1`:

```
df['pairing'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(zip(x[:-1], x[1:])), 1)
print(df)
```

Output

```
   Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5                           pairing
0       3       2       4       2       2  [(3, 2), (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 2)]
1       6       7       7       6       6  [(6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 6), (6, 6)]
```

Comment: output is this  [(3, 2), (2, 2), (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 2), (2, [(nan, 3.0), (3.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 4.0), (4.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, nan)])]

i want this only : [(3, 2), (2, 2), (2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 2)]